# Is there any way to get old record and new record within orient db hook

Tags: orientdb

I'm new to Orient db and trying to read old record and the new record within orient db "onBeforeUpdate" hook. New record can get from the "doc" variable within hook. But i need to get old record within that hook to compare with the new record. Is there any method or work around to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get old record by querying the doc.field('@rid'). But you need to specifically say "nocache" in the query. Otherwise db query will give you the updated record with old @version number.

Sample Query : SELECT FROM #46:66 NOCACHE